# Is it possible to use php 7 on IIS 6.0?

Tags: php, iis

I was wondering if it's possible to install PHP 7 on IIS 6.0, I have laravel 7 project and I want it to run on my server using IIS 6.0. I tried installing the PHP for windows but it got an error I think its because of the PHP version, I surf the internet for answers and I kinda found out that IIS 6.0 only supports PHP 5.x.x  I forgot the version, but I have a laravel 7 which needs a PHP 7 and later. Do I need to upgrade to the latest version of IIS and install the latest version of Window Server? My server is using Windows Server 2003.

Comment: First-off... why are you running Server 2003 today? It’s 17 years old!!!

Comment: I forgot to upgrade it, I was using C# for my website then I switched to PHP and then I realize that my server was really old and doesn't support the latest PHP version. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: PHP stops supporting Windows Server 2003 a long while ago, https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php

Comment: @LexLi could you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes from [PHP homepage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php)

> "PHP 5.5+ require at least Windows 2008/Vista, or 2008r2, 2012, 2012r2, 2016 or 7, 8, 8.1, 10. Either 32-Bit or 64-bit (aka X86 or X64. PHP does not run on Windows RT/WOA/ARM). As of PHP 7.2.0 Windows 2008 and Vista are no longer supported."

So you can see Windows Server 2003 is never supported by PHP 7.x. It is too old and should rest in peace now.